# How to use ITestEventListener in Nunit 3 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-addins

The steps I have taken:

1. I have created a separate project for the ITestEventListener
2. Installed Nunit.Engine.Api v3.9.0 for the new project
3. The class A that implements ITestEventListener has the `[ExtensionAttribute]`
4. The project that contains class A at root also has `.addins` file which contains `*dll` line (to reference all dlls in its directory)
5. The test project contains a reference to the project that has class A that implements ITestEventListener.

When I try to run a test, nothing happens. Solution Explorer keeps loading indefinitely.

I have not been able to find any step by step instructions for configuring this.

I had followed the official nunit [docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Engine-Extensibility#locating-addins)

as well as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749270/how-to-use-itesteventlistener-in-nunit-3) without success.

I am trying to run my tests with Visual Studio 2017 no the console runner

Any suggestions or pointers? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the NUnit 3 Adapter currently loads Extensions. They should work with the Console Runner however.

See the open issue here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/222

Comment: Im going to try to manually copy over the files. I just wanted to clarify what goes in the .addins file i create for the new project that I created containing ITestEventListener, is it the path to the dll that contains my class that implements the ItestEventListener or something else? It wasn't very clear to me

Comment: Yes, that's correct. See one of the default versions, here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/msi/resources/nunit.bundle.addins

Comment: Awesome thanks. Looks like manual copy and paste is not a solution. It is not supported with the Test Adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Would be a nice little Pull Request if you were interested, though! ;-)

Comment: Well. "Little" might not be the best choice of word here!